# Adding columns and calculating average/max values in a dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python

I am new to the Pandas library in Python and would like to aggregate data for data structured like this: Col A, Col B, Col C, Col D

I was able to use Pandas's groupby function to group Col A and B. What I wanted to do then is to determine the max of Col C per Col A/B combination and the average of Col D per Col A/B combination.

The output is essentially similar to what would happen if I run a SQL statement against the dataset

```
SELECT Col A, Col B, Max(Col C), Average(Col D)
FROM Data
GROUP BY Col A, Col B
```

Here is some code:

```
groupedResults = df.groupby(["ColA","ColB"],as_index=False).sum()
```

More specifically, I think the problem is how I can run 2 functions against the same dataset after calling the groupby function. I can sum it, max it across the data but having new columns to specifically display the max and average per col A and B is where I run into problems.

Comment: Give it a try and show us your code.

Comment: groupedResults =df.groupby(["ColA","ColB"],as_index=False).sum()
Thanks John More specifically, I think the problem is how I can run 2 functions against the same dataset after calling the groupby function. I can sum it, max it across the data but having new columns to specifically display the max and average per col A and B is where I run into problems